# React-redux reducer without switch case

Tags: react-native, react-redux, switch-statement, action, reducers

I am using react-redux for my app. I am facing a problem.
I have the following product reducer, but I do not want to use switch case as the below cases are my different screen of products.
On use switch case, the Offers screen is getting empty when I load vegProducts.

//in the productsreducer

```
  const initialState = {};
    
    export const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SET_OFFERS:
          return {
            offers: action.offers,
          };
        case SET_VPRODUCTS:
          return {
            vegProducts: action.vegProducts,
          };
        case SET_NPRODUCTS:
          return {
            nvegProducts: action.nvegProducts,
          };
      }
      return state;
    };
```

I am calling different reducers in my App.js as below

```
import productsReducer from './store/reducers/products';
import cartReducer from './store/reducers/cart';
import ordersReducer from './store/reducers/orders';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  orders: ordersReducer,
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have spent almost 3 days searching the internet for solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should append the data to the state, not replacing it. change it to:

```
  const initialState = {};
    
    export const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SET_OFFERS:
          return {
            ...state, // <--- add this to append offers to state
            offers: action.offers,
          };
        case SET_VPRODUCTS:
          return {
            ...state, // <--- add this
            vegProducts: action.vegProducts,
          };
        case SET_NPRODUCTS:
          return {
            ...state, // <--- add this
            nvegProducts: action.nvegProducts,
          };
      }
      return state;
    };
```

To understand how it works:

```
let state = {a: 1, b: 2} // <-- the state
{...state} // {a: 1, b: 2} <-- spread operator spreads the properties of the object
{b: 3} // {b: 3} <-- currently your doing this 
{...state, b: 3} // {a: 1, b: 3} <-- you should instead append b to state, like this
{...state, a: 5} // {a: 5, b: 2} <-- appending a to state
```

Comment: Really grateful to you. Kind Sir! Thank you again.

Comment: @Sva No problem, happy codding :)